# Enviar datos a una db en cierto día y hora (ojalá sin cronjobs)

Tags: php

Necesito enviar a mi base de datos un "1" en cierto día y hora, además enviar un "0" en otro día y hora.

Por ejemplo, Que cuando sea Jueves y sean las 13:30 horas, envíe un "1", y cuando sea Sábado y sean las 09:00 horas, envíe un "0".

Esos días,horas y ese "1" / "0" están en la misma tabla, como muestra la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces interpretando esas columnas, cuando se cumpla el horario de `inicio` (Viernes,00:00) se actualiza la columna `habilitada` con un "1", cuando se cumpla el horario de `termino` (Sabado,12:00), se actualiza la columna "habilitada" con un "0".

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora y funciona pero solo cuando recargo el archivo.php en el minuto de coincidencia:

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");     
  $hoy = getdate();       

  $dia = $hoy["wday"];
  $dias = ["Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado"];
  $dia = $dias[$dia];                   //nombre del día actual
  $hora = $hoy["hours"];               //la hora
  $minuto = $hoy["minutes"];               //minutos

  if($hora < 10) $ceroh = "0";         //cero extra por estética de la hora
  else $ceroh = "";                             
  if($minuto < 10) $cerom = "0";         //cero extra por estética de los minutos
  else $cerom = "";

  $diahora = $dia.",".$ceroh.$hora.":".$cerom.$minuto;  //dia y hora actual (dia,hh:mm)

  include 'connect.php';

  foreach($db->query("SELECT inicio,termino FROM `horario_envio`") as $fila){
    $inicio = htmlentities($fila['inicio']);            //hora inicio en la db
    $termino= htmlentities($fila['termino']);           //hora termino en la db
  }

  if($diahora == $inicio){        //si día y hora actual son iguales al campo inicio
    $si = "1";
    $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE `horario_envio` SET habilitada = :si");
        $update->bindValue(':si',$si,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $update->execute();    //pongo el "1"
  }
  if($diahora == $termino){     //si dia y hora actual son iguales al campo termino
    $no = "0";
    $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE `horario_envio` SET thabilitada = :no");
        $update->bindValue(':no',$no,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $update->execute();    //pongo el "0"
  }
?>
```

He investigado en el stackoverflow en inglés y, si he entendido bien, la mayoría sugiere el uso de cron-jobs para tareas similares, también he visto vídeos de su uso y lo que hacen es irse al control panel de su hosting y ahí programan la ejecución de ciertas tareas.

Pero yo no quiero eso, necesito que mi envío de datos se lleve a cabo solo según  la hora de inicio y término que mostré más arriba, que están en mi db.

En [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759843/automatically-schedule-a-php-script-execution-at-specific-time) post, el usuario @cmc dió tres soluciones, la primera es con cron, la segunda es con un ciclo infinito, lo cual recomendó como última instancia, y la tercera opción es **user driven**.

Esa tercera opción me llamó más la atención pues no estoy trabajando con grandes cantidades de datos. El problema es que no sé cómo aplicar lo que sugiere el autor de esa respuesta o tal vez simplemente no me sirva, es esto:

```
// you can simply include a the job this in your page footer, when there is no more output.

<?php

//fetch $last_exec_timestamp from database

if ($last_exec_timestamp < time() + 86400) {
  //set last_exec_timestamp to now in database

  //do something
}
```

No entiendo cómo podría aplicar eso a mi caso, lo que dice es algo como:

- *incluye esto en el footer de tu página cuando dejen de haber salidas*
- *toma la última ejecución de tiempo de la db*
- *si ese valor que acabas de tomar, es menor al tiempo actual + 24 horas:*

  - *setea la última ejecución de tiempo a la hora actual de la db*
  - *has algo.*

En fín, no sé cómo aplicar eso.

Estoy intentando hacer esto en php, pero si no fuera posible y existiera otra vía para hacer lo que describí al principio, igual podría aplicarla, incluso si la única vía fuese cron-jobs.

Gracias por su atención.

**EDIT**

**¿Por qué no me sirve cron?**

Los valores "inicio" y "termino" de la tabla que puse arriba controlarán el rango de horas, que son y "deben ser" modificables desde el frontend del sitio, entonces nunca habrá un rango de horas fijo, va a variar dependiendo de lo que elija el administrador desde la plataforma y se inserte en la base de datos.

Ejemplificando un poco: Quiero ofrecer un programa que permita a mi cliente establecer un rango de horas entre las cuales sus empleados podrán enviar ciertos datos a una base de datos. Y no quiero que mi cliente tenga que usar cron cuando quiera cambiar ese horario, sino que lo haga automáticamente desde el frontend.

Comment: pues, en mi opinión, para este tipo de cosas lo mejor es usar un cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a las restricciones que esta pregunta presentaba (no usar cron-jobs, no usar mysql event_scheduler por estar deshabilitado en hosting gratuitos) y gracias a las respuestas que me han venido dando los usuarios, hemos concluido que la manera más adecuada de hacer el trabajo que requiero (permitir acciones dentro de un rango temporal), es desarrollar un algoritmo que evalúe si actualmente se está dentro del rango temporal para ejecutar el envío de datos.

Inicialmente expuse la tabla con la cual estaba trabajando, donde quería poner un "1" o un "0" a cierta hora en el campo de la columna "habilitada":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ni siquiera necesitaba ese campo, pues para desarrollar un algoritmo que me permita evaluar si actualmente se está dentro del rango de horas predeterminado por los campos "inicio" y "termino", solo necesito esos dos campos.

Entonces lo que hice fue, primeramente traer esos dos campos a mi archivo php, también se obtuvo el día y la hora actual, entonces con esos tres datos (dia/hora de `inicio`, `actual` y de `termino`) procedo a darle cierta prioridad a todos los días de la semana según el día de `inicio`, eso me permitirá darle valores numéricos a los días de `inicio`, `actual` y `termino`, considerando también la hora de `inicio`, `actual` y `termino` para llevar a cabo la condición que me dirá si efectivamente se está dentro del rango o no.

Dejo el código por si a alguien le interesa:

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");     
$hoy = getdate();       

$dia = $hoy["wday"];
$dias = ["Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado"];
$dia = $dias[$dia];                  //nombre del día actual

$hora = $hoy["hours"];              //la hora
$minuto = $hoy["minutes"];      //los minutos

if($hora < 10) $ceroh = "0";
else $ceroh = "";

if($minuto < 10) $cerom = "0";
else $cerom = "";

$diahora = $dia.",".$ceroh.$hora.$cerom.$minuto;  //day,time actual

include 'connect.php';

foreach($db->query("SELECT inicio,termino FROM `horario_envio`") as $fila){
  $inicio = htmlentities($fila['inicio']);    //dia,hora de inicio
  $termino= htmlentities($fila['termino']);   //dia,hora de termino
}

$diai = strtok($inicio, ",");                      //obtengo el dia de inicio
$diat = strtok($termino, ",");                 //obtengo el dia de termino

if($diai == "Lunes"){
    $prioridad = array("Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado","Domingo");
    $pda = array_search($dia, $prioridad);  //prioridad dia actual
    $pdt = array_search($diat, $prioridad); //prioridad dia termino
}
if($diai == "Martes"){
    $prioridad = array("Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado","Domingo","Lunes");
    $pda = array_search($dia, $prioridad);  //prioridad dia actual
    $pdt = array_search($diat, $prioridad); //prioridad dia termino
}
if($diai == "Miercoles"){
    $prioridad = array("Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado","Domingo","Lunes","Martes");
    $pda = array_search($dia, $prioridad);  //prioridad dia actual
    $pdt = array_search($diat, $prioridad); //prioridad dia termino
}
if($diai == "Jueves"){
    $prioridad = array("Jueves","Viernes","Sabado","Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles");
    $pda = array_search($dia, $prioridad);  //prioridad dia actual
    $pdt = array_search($diat, $prioridad); //prioridad dia termino
}
if($diai == "Viernes"){
    $prioridad = array("Viernes","Sabado","Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves");
    $pda = array_search($dia, $prioridad);  //prioridad dia actual
    $pdt = array_search($diat, $prioridad); //prioridad dia termino
}
if($diai == "Sabado"){
    $prioridad = array("Sabado","Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes");
    $pda = array_search($dia, $prioridad);  //prioridad dia actual
    $pdt = array_search($diat, $prioridad); //prioridad dia termino
}
if($diai == "Domingo"){
    $prioridad = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado");
    $pda = array_search($dia, $prioridad);  //prioridad dia actual
    $pdt = array_search($diat, $prioridad); //prioridad dia termino
}

$pdi = 0;                                    //prioridad dia inicio

$hini = substr($inicio, -5);
$hter = substr($termino, -5);
$hini = (int)str_replace(":", "", $hini);   //obtengo la hora de inicio en números
$hter = (int)str_replace(":", "", $hter);   //obtengo la hora de termino en números
$hact = (int)substr($diahora, -4);       //obtengo la hora actual en números

if(($pda>$pdi or ($pda==$pdi and $hact>=$hini)) and ($pda<$pdt or ($pda==$pdt and $hact<$hter))){
    $sepuede = true;                        //evalúo si el día y hora actual están dentro
}else $sepuede = false;                 // del rango de horas preestablecido

if($sepuede){                         //si se está dentro del rango de horas:
    $rut = $_POST["rut"];             //hago el insert con los datos enviados
    $pedidos = $_POST["pedidos"];
    $update = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `t...
    $update->execute();
}
else echo "no";

?>
```

Entonces en el frontend llamo a este archivo con la función $.ajax de JQuery, pasándole los datos que aquí estoy recibiendo mediante POST, si en el success recibo un "no", daré una alerta para que el usuario sepa que sus turnos no se enviaron por estar fuera del rango de hora.

El código funciona perfectamente, pero cualquier sugerencia para optimizarlo es bienvenida.

Gracias a todos por sus aportes.

Answer (score 1):

### Para responder a tu pregunta

Lo que [esa respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15760383/255257) que mencionas, el autor quiere decir es que incluyas tu tarea al final del script con el que generas las páginas de tu sitio.

Suponiendo que tienes uno o varios scripts con los que generas el contenido de tu sitio, al final de dicho(s) script(s) podrías hacer las llamadas necesarias para que tu tarea se lleve a cabo. De esta manera, cada vez que haya un *hit* en tu sitio, se ejecutará dicho código y por tanto podría llevarse a cabo la tarea que te interesa.

Supongamos que originalmente tienes un `index.php` con este contenido:

```
<?php
  echo "hola, bienvenido a mi sitio";
?>
```

Al final, coloca el código que ya tienes en una función (la voy a llamar `actualizarStatusDB`) y tu script podría quedar algo así:

```
<?php
  include 'miFuncion.php';

  //acá inicia tu script original
  echo "hola, bienvenido a mi sitio";
  //acá terminar tu script original

  actualizarStatusDB();  //llamada a la función que actualiza el status
?>
```

En este caso, tu página debe tener al menos un *hit* por minuto, para que esto funcione, y por eso es que el autor original inicia diciendo:

> If you have a decent amount of traffic on your site...

Si el tráfico de tu página es menor, debes realizar ajustes en tu script para que, por ejemplo, cambie el valor en la DB en la primera llamada después de la hora. Aún así, requieres de un monto decente de tráfico para lograrlo.

### La parte analítica

Ahora, dado que mencionas que estás en un hosting gratuito, me pregunto yo, ¿para qué necesitas ese valor actualizado en la base de datos? Ya que esta seguramente también está cerrada y dudo que puedas utilizarla para una integración con un sistema externo... piensa, ¿por qué debe estar actualizado?

Si lo necesitas para el propio funcionamiento de tu sitio, mi consejo es: olvida el campo en la DB y deriva el valor cada vez que lo necesites.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, veo que no me sirve  el user driven. Respecto a La parte analítica, necesito que ese dato esté actualizado pues la idea es permitirle a los usuarios de mi plataforma web, enviar ciertos datos dentro de un rango de horas, entonces con ese "1" o "0" podré verificar si actualmente se está o ya se salió de tal rango. Si se te ocurre alguna otra forma de hacerlo, por favor házmelo saber, quizá yo me estoy complicando demasiado, ojalá que sea así. Por cierto, los valores "inicio" y "termino" de mi db son modificables desde el frontend del sitio, por eso no me sirve cron.

Comment: Pues simplemente cada vez que vas a enviar un dato, valida si la hora actual está dentro del rango permitido en la configuración, y en caso de no estarlo, no procesas la petición sino respondes con un error.

Comment: En algo así estoy trabajando en este momento, creo que por ahí va la cosa, solo tengo que crear bien ese gran if de validación, se me hace difícil pues debo evaluar los días de la semana y las horas que traigan, darles cierta jerarquía dinámica a esos días para establecer bien el rango cuando tenga, por ejemplo en cualquier hora: inicio: Miércoles, termino: Viernes. O un inicio: Viernes, termino: Miércoles. O un inicio: Domingo, termino: Domingo(un poco mas tarde).

Comment: Es la misma lógica la que tienes que desarrollar para poner 0 o 1 en tu campo derivado, es decir, no implica más trabajo. Encapsula la lógica en una función y será tan simple de hacer y utilizar como la solución que pensaste primero, pero esta es la ruta por la que si te funcionará.

Comment: en unas horas quizá lo tenga.

Comment: lo he logrado! aunque ya la solución se sale del marco de mi pregunta original pues no he necesitado añadir ese "1" o "0", simplemente he hecho la evaluación del rango de horas tomando la hora de inicio, termino, y la hora actual.

Qué debería hacer? publico la solución final o no corresponde por salirse del marco de la pregunta?

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo Pon una respuesta indicando que no hay solución posible debido a las restricciones que te has autoimpuesto, y a las restricciones que te pone tu servicio de hosting (enumera cuáles son), y luego explica la alternativa que te han aconsejado, y como la has desarrollado, porque te has dado cuenta que es la alternativa correcta a tu problema real (permitir acción en un rango temporal). Has sido víctima del llamado problema XY, que es preguntar sobre (Y) tu solución, en vez de preguntar sobre (X) tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Yo también me pregunto por qué no hacerlo mediante `cron` aunque
expones que " la idea es permitirle a los usuarios de mi plataforma web, enviar ciertos datos dentro de un rango de horas".No me queda claro, ¿enviar correos desde tu plataforma web? o ¿enviar datos a una base de datos ?. En cualquier caso la función que se encarga de enviar "esos datos" pudiera chequear si se está ejecutando en el horario establecido (dígase una programación preestablecida o gestionable igualmente) para el usuario o para todos los usuarios de la plataforma.
Y si te vas por el cron, pues el simplemente cron estará ejecutando el contenido de un fichero, por tanto ahí estará la llamada al menos a una función que será la encargada de validar si se está dentro del horario permitido para "enviar ciertos datos"

Mejorando la respuesta:  partamos de lo siguiente: tu aplicación tiene usuarios, ya sea en calidad de manager (llamémosle así) y otros usuarios bajo el rol empleado (aunque un manager es un empleado también, pero dejémoslo simple).

- Los usuarios manager tendrán capacidad de crear (desde el frontend
  dices tu) calendarizaciones para el envío de información, cómo??:
  desde una UI escojen fecha y hora de inicio y fin del periodo
  permitido para enviar información.

  Y los usuarios empleados, tratarán de enviar información en un momento determinado del día.

Simplemente tu sistema (tu plataforma web) deberá ser capaz de verificar que el momento (fecha y hora) en el que el empleado intenta enviar la información, está dentro del intervalo de la calendarización creada por el usuario manager. Creo tu problema no es tanto de programación sino de diseño de tu sistema.

Es por ello que hacemos incapiés en la parte analítica

Comment: Lo que sucede es que los valores "inicio" y "termino" de la tabla que puse arriba, son modificables desde el frontend del sitio, por eso no me sirve cron, nunca habrá un rango de horas fijo, va a variar dependiendo de lo que elija el administrador desde la plataforma. En pocas palabras, quiero ofrecer un programa que permita a mi cliente establecer un rango de horas entre las cuales sus empleados podrán enviar ciertos datos a una base de datos. Y no quiero que mi cliente tenga que usar cron cuando quiera cambiar ese horario, sino que lo haga automáticamente en el frontend.

Comment: mmmm, partamso de lo siguiente: tu aplicación tiene usuarios, ya sea en calidad de manager, llamémosle así, y otros usuarios bajo el rol empleado.

Comment: exacto, así es mi aplicación.

Comment: Lo he logrado!, debería publicarla como respuesta o debería editar mi pregunta original?

Comment: @Roberto, sugiero que no cambies completamente la pregunta original, pues las respuestas ya no tendrían sentido. Puedes ampliarla para indicar las restricciones que existen y publicar tu propia solución como respuesta siempre es bienvenido.

Answer (score 0):

hola puedes crear un cron job a nivel de OS o puedes calendarizar un evento en tu base de datos, te dejo un el link de un ejemplo de calendarizacion de eventos en 
mysql:
https://donnierock.com/2013/01/30/eventos-en-mysql-planificar-tareas-fecha/

saludos,

Comment: Ya vi ese camino pero resulta que en los hosting gratis, tienen el event_scheduler deshabilitado y por razones obvias, tampoco se puede activar con SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; como aparece en el artículo que linkeas, ahora bien, si sabes de algún hosting gratuito que lo maneje activado, sería estupendo.

Comment: si tienes acceso al phpmyadmin (asumiendo que utilizas mysql) puedes crearlo desde ahíi de forma gráfica

Comment: Pero lo primero es que esto: SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; functione. Y si no tienes privilegios de super usuario no podrás hacerlo, o por lo menos eso entendí de esto: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/set-global-event-scheduler-on/25994

Comment: otra opción puede ser que uses  amazon cloud o digitalOcean por un periodo de prueba y tu mismo instales mysql y crees los eventos si no deseas utilizar el cron job del panel de administración de tu hosting, ya que hosting gratuitos que no tengan bloqueados esas funcionalidades no recuerdo ninguno

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de hacerlo sería almacenarte en la base de datos la última fecha de ejecución del cron y que al ejecutar tu archivo .php lo unico que haga sea checkear si ha pasado o no una hora.

Cuando eso ya esté funcionando es obligatorio que ejecutes un cron cada hora con tu archivo .php para que ejecute las tareas que necesitas.

El cron puede ser a nivel de linux o con módulos plugins de tu cms si es que tienes.